# Choose index.html above index.php when there is one

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the case:

You can request a demo for a specific product online. That's what we will do:

We will create a **subdomain** on our server and **clone + install** the code of our online product. A **cron runs every day** and when your subdomain exists 14 days we want to place an **index.html** in the subdomain with some info on it.

Now the problem is that the index.html doesn't do anything. In our **.htaccess** we have the following:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

As you can see we have a RewriteRule to index.php otherways the code doesn't work. How can I make sure that the index.html is loaded.

Also another problem is that when you're logged in you're automatically go to **/admin**, so if there's no admin folder he will give an error.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `DirectoryIndex index.html` into your .htaccess.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: I've added the rule under RewriteRule .* index.php but it didn't change anything ... .

Comment: Is your problem that the page doesn't show when you access http:// <subdomain.url> /, or when you try http:// <subdomain.url> /index.html? If the former, that apache config change might/should help. If the latter, then the index.html file isn't in the right place.

Comment: When I go to http://subdomain.url/index.html I can see the html page. But he still goes to the index.php and then to the login page .. I just want to show the index.html

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. If you can see the html page, then that is working. I don't know what "he still goes to the index.php" means.